# app real path issue in spock integration test case

Tags: grails, testing, integration-testing, spock, realpath

I am working on integration test case of an action which generate `pdf` using `jasper`. That jasper have a `sub-report`. To get the path of the sub-report (`abc.jasper` in `web-app/reports/`) I am first fetching real path using

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")
```

which gives `/home/mkb/workspace/my-project/web-app` and then concatenating `/reports/abc.jasper` to get the sub-report in parent jasper report. This is working fine when running the application (run-app).

But while testing (test-app) above code giving `/home/mkb/workspace/my-project/target/work/scriptCache` and hence I am getting

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : 
/home/mkb/workspace/my-project/target/work/scriptCache/reports/abc.jasper
```

**How can I set or fix this path issue in test cases?** (Grails 2.3.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [ServletContextHolder](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/context/ServletContextHolder.html) class static method getRealPath() to get the real path.e.g :-

```
ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('/')
```

This code will give the path of web-app folder of your application.